# Databound ListPicker SelectedItem goes blank when modifying SelectedIndex

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, listpicker

I have a ListPicker in my Windows Phone 7 app where both the **ItemsSource** and **SelectedIndex** properties are bound to my ViewModel. SelectedIndex is using **Two Way** binding. The items and the SelectedIndex are correctly populated on application startup. However, when I modify the SelectedIndex property in my ViewModel the ListPicker's TextBox goes blank, as if there was no selected item. If I go to full mode and check which is the selected item from the list, the correct item is being selected.

Here is the ListPicker xaml code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="TheListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=Resources.TheHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" SelectedIndex="{Binding TheCurrentIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsViewEnabled}" TabIndex="0" >
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="item" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 24, 0, 24">
                <TextBlock Margin="15, 0, 0, 0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

This is a simplified version of my ViewModel:

```
[DataMember]
public ObservableCollection<ItemEntity> TheItems
{
    get
    {
        if (this.theItems == null)
        {
            this.theItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemEntity>();
        }

        return this.theItems;
    }
    set
    {
        this.theItems = value;
    }
}

[DataMember]
public int TheCurrentIndex
{
    get 
    {
        return this.theCurrentIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.theCurrentIndex)
        {
            this.theCurrentIndex = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TheCurrentIndex");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSomeOtherPropertyEnabled");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant code from MainPage.xaml.cs (App_ViewModelChanged is an event handler invoked when some async stuff performed on application startup finishes):

```
private void App_ViewModelChanged(object sender, ViewModelChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    BindToViewModel();
}

private void BindToViewModel()
{
    this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    this.ViewModel.IsViewEnabled = true;
}

private void SomeAsyncMethodCompleted(object sender, DetectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        this.ViewModel.TheCurrentIndex = e.Result;
    }
}
```

This issue is not happening all the time. Happens like 50% of the time. It seems to happen only once in the application lifetime and then never happens again. Also, the issue started appearing when I switched from the Feb 2011 release of the Silverlight Control Toolkit to the Aug 2011 release. Never had this issue before.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want SelectedItem instead?

Comment: I started using SelectedIndex with the hope that it would solve this same issue that was happening when using SelectedItem. So it pretty much doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Could you share some code with us, maybe that could help solve the problem

Comment: Just added some code. Very simplified from the real version, but enough to get the idea.

Comment: I try to find out what type you get from DetectCompletedEventArgs.Result, but i seem to find only examples where you get a string and not an int, but maybe that depends on your AsyncMethod.

Comment: Yes, don't pay atention to that. DetectCompletedEventArgs is a custom class created by me. e.Result is just an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the reason for this strange behavior was a small change in the ListPickerItem style in Aug 2011 Silverlight Control Toolkit.

This is how it looks in Aug 2011 release:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ListPickerItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 10"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <!-- More Stuff Here -->
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is how it looked in Feb 2011 release:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ListPickerItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <!-- More Stuff Here -->
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

See the difference? They changed the ListPickerItem Padding to **8 10** in the new release and somehow that was causing the issue. Reverting to **8 6** fixes it. Don't ask me why.

So in my project I didn't actually modified the control toolkit Generic.xaml file, but just modified the specific ListPicker resources to specify a new padding for the ListPickerItem style, like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="TheListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=Resources.TheHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" SelectedIndex="{Binding TheCurrentIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsViewEnabled}" TabIndex="0" >           
    <toolkit:ListPicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="toolkit:ListPickerItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 6"/>
        </Style>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.Resources>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>           
        <DataTemplate>           
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">           
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />           
            </StackPanel>           
        </DataTemplate>           
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>           
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>           
        <DataTemplate>           
            <StackPanel x:Name="item" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5, 24, 0, 24">           
                <TextBlock Margin="15, 0, 0, 0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" />           
            </StackPanel>           
        </DataTemplate>           
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>           
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Such a small change!